# .htaccess commands disables redriect

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess has 2 lines wich adds `/` at the end of each page, lke `domain.com/contact/` today i figured out thats what prevent my registration page from redirecting to the login page after registration. It acctually cancels the whole registration process.

Full .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^http://razor.avatarland.org$               [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_styles.css} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]



#ERROR CODE -----------------------------------------------------------
ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

#Folder access-------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule    ^admin/?$                            /404.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^css/?$                              /404.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^download/?$                         /404.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^etc/?$                              /404.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^images/?$                           /404.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^password_protect/?$                 /404.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^profiles/?$                         /404.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^tos/?$                              /404.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^warning/?$                          /404.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^Tos-and-rules/?$                    /terms.php                      [NC,L]


#Error---------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule    ^400/?$                          /400.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^401/?$                          /401.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^403/?$                          /403.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^404/?$                          /404.php                        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^500/?$                          /500.php                        [NC,L]


#Main----------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule    ^//?$                            /index.php                      [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^about/?$                        /about.php                      [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^contact/?$                      /contact.php                    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^misc/?$                         /misc.php                       [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^upload/?$                       /upload.php                     [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^forum/?$                        /forum.php                      [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^chat/?$                         /chat/index.php                 [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^denied/?$                       /denied.php                     [NC,L]



#Admin----------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule    ^adminpanel/?$                   /adminpanel.php                 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^adminpanel/admin-rules/?$       /admin-rules.php                [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^adminpanel/promote-demote/?$    /admin/promote-demote.php       [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^adminpanel/log/?$               /admin/admin-log.php            [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^adminpanel/reported/?$          /admin/reported.php             [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^adminpanel/log/promoted-demoted/?$      /admin/promoted-demoted-log.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^adminpanel/log/warnings/?$              /admin/warnings.php             [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^adminpanel/log/unban/?$                 /admin/unban.php                [NC,L]

#Misc----------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule    ^misc/members/?$                 /members.php                    [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^misc/download/?$                /download.php                   [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^misc/top-members/?$             /top-members.php                [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^misc/games/?$                   /games.php                      [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^misc/sheepa/?$                  /sheepa.php                     [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^misc/sheepa/web-stat?$          /etc/sheepa_website.php         [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^misc/awards?$                   /awardlist.php                  [NC,L] 


#Etc-----------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule    ^credits/?$                      /etc/credits.php                [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^help/?$                         /etc/help.php                   [NC,L]


#Banned--------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule    ^banned/?$                       /banned.php                     [NC,L] 


#User----------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule    ^signin/?$                       /login.php                      [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^signout/?$                      /logout.php                     [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^signup/?$                       /register.php                   [NC,L]  
RewriteRule    ^user/0/?$                       /nouser.php                     [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^inbox/?$                        /profiles/inbox.php             [NC,L]  
RewriteRule    ^settings/?$                     /settings.php                   [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^settings/change-email-pw/?$     /profiles/change-info.php       [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^settings/change-bio/?$          /profiles/change-bio.php        [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^settings/change-avatar/?$       /profiles/change-avatar.php     [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^settings/change-clan_tag/?$     /profiles/change-clantag.php    [NC,L]


RewriteRule    ^etc/bb-code/?$                  /etc/bb-codes.php               [NC,L]

RewriteRule report/user/(.*)/ report_usere.php?id=$1
RewriteRule report/user/(.*) report_user.php?id=$1  


#Users------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/user\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^user/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [L]


#Message------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/message\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^message/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^message/([0-9]+)/?$ message.php?id=$1 [L]



#Message / Read--------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule read-message/(.*)/ read-message.php?link=$1
RewriteRule read-message/(.*) read-message.php?link=$1  


#Password------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule    ^reset-password/?$                       /password_protect/reset-pass.php                [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^reset-password/ticket/?$                /password_protect/pass_ticket.php               [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^reset-password/email-username/?$        /password_protect/pass_email_username.php       [NC,L]


#Forum------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule forum/(.*)/ forum_threads.php?link=$1
RewriteRule forum/(.*) forum_threads.php?link=$1    


#Members----------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule misc/members/(.*)/ members.php?page=$1
RewriteRule misc/members/(.*) members.php?page=$1   

#Top-Members----------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule misc/top-members/(.*)/ top-members.php?page=$1
RewriteRule misc/top-members/(.*) top-members.php?page=$1   


#add friend-------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule user/addfriend/(.*)/ friend_system.php?id=$1
RewriteRule user/addfriend/(.*) friend_system.php?id=$1
```

is there any other way to get same result but without ruin my code?

Comment: @anubhava i have added my full .htaccess now, the only known problem with it is `header('location: /signin')` and sending the data to the database

Comment: Which php file has `header('location: /signin')` code?

Comment: My registration, it works fine without the 2 first lines i shared but some how isnt able to redirect or send the information to database when i include the part of .htaccess